# Angular 6, Map http response to a Model

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am currently researching how I can map an http response to a defined model in angular.

In such a way that I can "push" the response into a class of my model, that only assigns the properties on the model and ignores all other.

Lets say that i have a user model that has

- Name
- Email

And the http response contains also

- UUID
- Status

As an end result, I would like to receive a User class that has the Name & Email properties filled out and the UUID and Status are just ignored.

I can't seem to find a clean example nor explanation about this.

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Typescript doesn't exist at runtime, only at compile time, so you'd need to code for this yourself. You can create a constructor on your `User` model that takes has a `name` and `email` parameter, and use the HTTP response to create a `User` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want something like

```
getUser(): Observable<User> {
  return this.httpClient.get<any>(url).pipe(
    map(data => new User(data.name, data.email))
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi JB, thanks for that suggestion. I am now working on enumerating the properties of User in the constructor. That works fine, but in my component when i try to render user.name for example, I get Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. When I instantiate an empty user class in the component it does work. Thats a little annoying, is there a way around this? Much appreciated the work you did for the answer that was incorrect! It allowed me to understand and learn.

Comment: `<div *ngIf="user">display the user here</here>`. You need to understand that http is asynchronous. So, even if you send a request to get the user when the component is initialized, the response will only come back later, asynchronously, and before that, the component is already displayed, with an uninitialized user.

Comment: Yes i know. That is also what i did now. Thought maybe there was a smarter thing to be done :) Many thanks. Gotta dig into that .pipe & map() thing though.

Comment: There is an alternative if the component is a routed component: use a resolve guard to load the data before activating the component.